# Ruby Caesar Cipher

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a Caesar Cipher in Ruby and I am not sure why my code is not working:

```
l_alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
u_alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a
num = 5
string = "Hello world, my name is Mark!"
newstring = ""
string.each_char do |a|
    if !l_alphabet.include?(a) && !u_alphabet.include?(a)
        newstring += a
    else
        if l_alphabet.include?(a)
            newstring += l_alphabet[l_alphabet.index(a) + num]
        else
            newstring += u_alphabet[u_alphabet.index(a) + num]
        end
    end    
end

puts newstring
```

I am getting these 4 errors and I am not sure what any of them mean.

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
(repl):11:in `+'
(repl):11:in `block in initialize'
(repl):6:in `each_char'
(repl):6:in `initialize'
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you are shifting your new string value out of the bounds of the original array. You have to modulo l_alphabet.index(a) + num % 26 to make sure it's within bounds.

Comment: Yup! That was the problem. Thanks for the help, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were extending the index beyond the bounds of the alphabet. You have to check if the letters index + num > 26(letters in alphabet). If it is, index = index % 26 to wrap the position back around to the front of the array.

```
l_alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
u_alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a
num = 5
string = "Hello world, my name is Mark!"
newstring = ""
string.each_char do |a|
    if !l_alphabet.include?(a) && !u_alphabet.include?(a)
        newstring += a
    else
        if l_alphabet.include?(a)
          index = l_alphabet.index(a) + num
          if index > 26 
            index = index % 26
          end
          newstring += l_alphabet[index]
        else
          index = u_alphabet.index(a) + num
          if index > 26
            index = index % 26
          end
            newstring += u_alphabet[index]
        end
    end    
    puts newstring
end
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: OP: if this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it as an answer, which helps keep SO tidy (or tidier).

Comment: I am so sorry. I didn't mean anything negative by my comment, I just got so excited I didn't think about it. I will try my best to never make the same mistake, please accept my apologies.

orde, I did have to look up how but I did accept the answer. Thank you as well.